# How to sort and pick the first few items in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question is kind of an extension of [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657654/how-do-you-normally-sort-items-in-rails), so I'll be using that as a baseline for this question.

Say I have a bunch of tickets that I would like fetched and sorted by name. That's easy enough, just do:

```
@tickets = Ticket.find(:all, :order => 'name')
```

However, is there a way to tell Ticket.find that I only want the first x tickets? I'm betting there's a way to do this with straight SQL, and I'm sure I could just take `@tickets` and shorten it to the first x elements, but I'd rather do it a straight Ruby way that doesn't acquire all the tickets (I have an awful lot of "tickets" and I don't really want to get them all, that could cost a lot of CPU time).

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you want to do is:

```
@tickets = Ticket.find(:all, :order => 'name', :limit => x)
```

Where `x` is how many records you want.

See [the Rails documentation](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) for more conditions you can put in your `find`.  (Search for `VALID_FIND_OPTIONS`.)

Comment: This is also covered in the Query Interface guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extension of the 'limit' parameter in SQL. For example, `SELECT * FROM ticket ORDER BY name LIMIT 4`. It is, thus, available in any ORM, including ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

..and if you're using Rails 3, you could make it

```
@tickets = Ticket.order('name').limit(x).all
```